# Hibernate mapping with none primary key table

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

There is a table without any primary keys on MySQL database. I want to use hibernate to access data side of java. However, hibernate could not parse mapping document. Other tables are mapped properly. Is this problem cause of none of the primary key? Must I create at least one primary key to map this table? Or is there anything else?

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (   `extension` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  `password` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,   `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   `voicemail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   `ringtimer` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,   `noanswer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,   `recording` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   `outboundcid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   `sipname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   `mohclass` varchar(80) DEFAULT 'default',   `noanswer_cid` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',   `busy_cid` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',   `chanunavail_cid` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',   `noanswer_dest` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',   `busy_dest` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',   `chanunavail_dest` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> **Exception:**
>
> ***org.hibernate.boot.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document: Users.hbm.xml (RESOURCE)***

Comment: table without primary key?

Comment: there is no primary key on table

Comment: You do not need a primary key. You seem to have an error in your Users.hbm.xml.

Comment: As per JPA specification or Mysql one class marked as entity must have at least one primary key,  same with Mysql table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Hibernate specification every entity should have Id, but if you don't have possibility to add Id to current table you still able to create class `User` without `Entity` annotation, and to map results of native query to this class.

Comment: How do I map results using native query? Could you explain that ?

Comment: With using of `SqlResultSetMapping` annotation you can specify connection of class fields and table fields, you can see some examples here: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-basics/